# Using MAX on a Subquery with a Having or Where Clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to query a list of all characters in the work with the most paragraphs in it.

First I did a count() on the paragraph table to find the work with the most paragraphs in it.

I am having a hard time querying the character list by using the first result.

```
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT paragraphs.id), works.id FROM works 
JOIN chapters ON works.id = chapters.work_id 
JOIN paragraphs ON chapters.id = paragraphs.chapter_id
GROUP BY works.Title)
```

How do I go about nesting this query?

Schema diagram below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following query:

```
WITH workid_with_most_paragraphs AS(
    SELECT c.work_id
    FROM       paragraphs p 
    INNER JOIN chapters c
            ON c.id = p.chapter_id
    GROUP BY c.work_id
    ORDER BY SUM(p.id) DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
SELECT *
FROM       chapters   
INNER JOIN paragraphs
        ON chapters.work_id = (SELECT work_id FROM workid_with_most_paragraphs)
       AND chapters.id = paragraphs.chapter_id
INNER JOIN characters 
        ON paragraphs.character_id = characters.id
```

The subquery (common table expression - cte) will catch the work which has the most paragraphs exploiting the join between *paragraphs* and *chapters* tables, hence ordering the result by the sum of paragraphs for each work id (`GROUP BY c.work_id ORDER BY SUM(p.id) DESC`) and truncating the result to single row (`LIMIT 1`).

Once you get the single work id, you can use the *chapters* table to gather the corresponding *work_id* value, the *paragraphs* table to gather the corresponding paragraphs, and the *characters* table to gather the needed information.

You don't need to query the *works* table at all as long as you don't need any information from that table other than the *work_id*, which can be found directly in the *chapters* table.

If you share samples from the tables I'll update this post with a tested answer.